# Setting working direction to direction of the script in Python (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, unix, pyinstaller

I have a pretty simple script that takes data from some .csv or .db files, performs manipulations and saves output in the similar files. I am working from Spyder with the parameter "Run in the directory of the file", so when I run the file my wd is set to file's directory automatically. SO that I put all files in one folder and do not mess with paths (e.g. using always `open("data.csv")`). And my files are stored like:

```
/Users/username/docs/script.py
/Users/username/docs/data.cv
/Users/username/docs/database.db
```

I've tried to use `pyinstaller` to that colleagues could you the script easily as well, but any time they would run it, it would set the working directory to `/Users/username/` and all relative paths are getting broken.

How could I preserve this issue, so that the script (pyinstaller shell script) would be taking as working directory the folder with its location, like Spyder is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using plain `open('data.csv')`, you should use a snippet like the following:

```py
import os
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    base_dir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


file = open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'data.csv'))
```

Then, when building you include your data files with `--add-data=data.csv;.`. Please use a colon (`:`) instead of a semi-colon (`;`) when *not* on Windows. If you're on Windows and using PowerShell, then escape the semi-colon with a backtick (`` ` ``).

Comment: thanks, it worked after I changed `sys._MEIPASS` to `sys.executable`, because `sys._MEIPASS` does not work for single-filed outputs of pyinstaller. Found that tip in other thread, yet I've lost it now...

Comment: @user1039698 actually `sys._MEIPASS` _does_ work, but you need to add the data files with the command line option `--add-data` command line option.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the getcwd() function in os module to get the location of the current working directory. Then open the files like this.

```
open(os.getcwd()+'/data.csv')
```